# How to select an element's great-grandchild for CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, joomla, css-selectors

Given this HTML, how can I select `rt-block` to alter the CSS *only when nested within rt-header* as shown?

```
<div id="rt-header">
    <div class="rt-container">
        <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-alpha">
            <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-omega">
                <div class="rt-block ">    // This is the occurrence I want to override
                    my html....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes *rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega* don't remain consistent, sometimes being a single div, depending on the Gantry/LESS settings.  If you're familiar with RT Templates used in Joomla, you'll know that  `rt-block` is used throughout, and so the class in general cannot be altered.

**UPDATE** - showing another possibility of HTML with the same need:

```
<div id="rt-header">
    <div class="rt-container">
        <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-alpha rt-omega">
            <div class="rt-block ">    // This is the occurrence I want to override
                my html....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: #rt-header .rt-container .rt-grid-6 .rt-grid-6 .rt-block ?

Comment: Are you wanting to style the .rt-block class, or style the .rt-header only if rt-block is present?

Comment: `#rt-header .rt-block` is all you'd need., unless you need to require any of those grid/alpha/omega bits as well.

Comment: @MarcB that's what I was thinking.

Comment: `.rt-header .rt-block` - this will style all rt-blocks that are descendants of rt-header.  which is fine if there is only one.  If there is more then one you need to get more specific with the selector list

Comment: I thinks this is it, I'l try, though I'd swear it didnt work early, the question!, lol

Comment: Do you need to account for any of those intermediate classes? Or do you just want any `.rt-block` so long as it descends from `#rt-header`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

General css hierarchy (at any nested level) is given by a simple space

So:

```
#rt-header .rt-block {
    /* CSS STYLE */
}
```

Comment: The sorcery of CSS....and a @#$% typo.....I was fighting with .rt-header .rt-block !!!!  Thanks for forcing fresh eyes!

Answer (score 5):

All that you need in order to select `.rt-block` when it is under `#rt-header` is simply (as Marc B answered in the comments):

```
#rt-header .rt-block { /* rules here */ }
```

For another, framework-agnostic example, let's say that you have a structure like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <section class="introduction">
    <p>Hello!</p>
  </section>
  <section class="overview">
    <p>This is an overview.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

and I wanted to target only `<p>` tags inside `<section class="introduction">`, no matter what the parent element is. You could write the CSS like this:

```
.introduction p { /* rules */ }
```