# Apply CSS selector for child element not having parent

Tags: css

I know there is a not operator in CSS that can be used at the root level. But can I apply CSS selector for child element not having a specific parent element ?

So I have a DOM structure as below;

```
<div>
<button value="applyCSSToThisBtn"/>
</div>
<div id="someId" class="someClass">
<button value="DONOTapplyCSSToThisBtn"/>
</div>
```

So basically I want to appy some CSS to the button (but only for that which does not have id="someId" as it's parent...Also button is not necessarily direct child)

Comment: `div:not(#someId) button {...`

Comment: button is not a self-closing tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select an element's great-grandchild for CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268914/how-to-select-an-elements-great-grandchild-for-css-rules)

Comment: @Heki No, that's not a duplicate for this question, although I'm sure many do exist

Comment: Yes, my question is I want to select only that element which does not have a specific parent/grandparent (so a NOT condition)

Answer (score 0):

```
div:not([id]) button {
  color: red;
}
```

How about this? Applies style to all `button`s that are children of a div without an `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to point to your button that doesn't have an specified property

```css
button{} //returns all buttons
    
button:not([id] {} //returns all buttons without id
```

Answer (score 0):

Css has a pseudo class not.

To select all those buttons which are children (or grandchildren etc) of a div where that div does not have id someId you can do this:

```css
div:not([id="someId"]) button {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button value="applyCSSToThisBtn">should be magenta</button>
</div>
<div id="someId" class="someClass">
  <button value="DONOTapplyCSSToThisBtn">should not be magenta</button>
</div>
```

Note: button is not self closing so this has been corrected in this snippet.

Comment: For some reason, while this works for your example, it is not working for me....though I have a smilar structure as your example...and have button nested deeply down inside the container div.

Comment: I think you'll need to give more code in your question that shows the actual structure because my example is the code you gave (except with the HTML errors corrected). Perhaps pass your actual code through a HTML/CSS validator too?

Answer (score 0):

This selects all descendants of a parent that don't have the specified id. Run the code to see the result

```css
div:not(#someId) button{background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<div>
<button>Child1</button>
<section><button>Grandchild</button></section>
</div>

<div id="someId" class="someClass">
<button>Child2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the others?

Comment: Includes an example of a descendant button tag. Other examples only show direct children, though their answers are nevertheless correct.